# Cannot add noexec to fstab /tmp/

Tags: mount, fstab, xfs

Does anyone know why my Graphical Interface does not load after reboot when I remove " noexec "  from fstab?

So if I remove the " noexec " from the /tmp/  entry in FSTAB, it will load the GUI fine after reboot. See the image below.

I already bind /tmp/ with /var/tmp/

```
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
/dev/mapper/ol_rhel7-root /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=af6b8325-9cf7-4618-9afd-99987eb8f3b3 /boot                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/ol_rhel7-home /home                   xfs     defaults,nodev        0 0
/dev/mapper/ol_rhel7-var /var                     xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/ol_rhel7-swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
/dev/sda5          /var/log                       xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/sdb1          /var/log/audit                 xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/sdc1          /tmp                           xfs     defaults,nodev,nosuid           0 0
/tmp               /var/tmp                       none    bind   0 0
tmpfs              /dev/shm                       tmpfs   defaults,nodev,nosuid,noexec     0 0
```

Comment: Do you have any logs from your GUI/display manager? The nature of the failure suggests that something is being tossed into /tmp and then executed as part of the GUI startup process.

Comment: I am not sure where to get those logs, could they be here?                /var/log/Xorg.0.log   I will get back to you later today.